# How to set custom thumbnail to a file in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, thumbnails

Is it possible to set custom (any image) thumbnail to a file (on per-file basis) in Windows File Explorer?

Suppose I would like to assign real book cover image to e-book in `*.txt` format.

Answer (score -1):

Atleast in XP that I'm in you can go to Tools->Folder settings->Filetypes where you can edit the filetypes by pressing Additional settings and pressing Change icon to change the icon type. Thats not per file basis though.

Comment: I want per file...

Comment: There is the possibility to assign custom icons to folders, but I don't think there is a way to assign custom icons to single files in the same manner. Only 2 other ways that come to my mind is to make a new file extension for the ebooks txt files, and assign that to open in the program you're using for reading ebooks. The other is to just make a shortcut to the file, for which you always can assign custom icons. Powertoys for windows has options to remove the arrow indicator from shortcuts so you'd have only the icon that looks like a book while still beeing only a shortcut.